# JWT Authentication in Symfony 4.3 with Guard

Tags: symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am new to symfony.

I am trying to implement JWT authentication using lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle v2.6 and Symfony v4.3
I implemented login successfully, it provides me with jwt token.
And accessing restricted areas with JWT token also working with following configuration in security.yml

```
login:
            pattern: ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
api:
            pattern: ^/
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

But this configuration giving following warning:
@deprecated since 2.0, use the "lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator" Guard

So I implemented my own App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
which extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
and changed

```
guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

to

```
guard:
            authenticators:
                #- lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
                - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
```

After changing configuration I am getting "Invalid JWT Token" error.
Error is thrown because in vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/Services/JWTManager.php (line 96)

```
    /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function decode(TokenInterface $token)
{
    if (!($payload = $this->jwtEncoder->decode($token->getCredentials()))) { //line 96
        return false;
    }

    $event = new JWTDecodedEvent($payload);
    if ($this->dispatcher instanceof ContractsEventDispatcherInterface) {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch($event, Events::JWT_DECODED);
    } else {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(Events::JWT_DECODED, $event);
    }

    if (!$event->isValid()) {
        return false;
    }

    return $payload;
}
```

$token is Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken
type and its getCredentials() function's implementation returning empty array:

```
    /**
 * This is meant to be only an authenticated token, where credentials
 * have already been used and are thus cleared.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCredentials()
{
    return [];
}
```

I cannot find a solution for it on Internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle bundle has its own implementation using Guard: [JWTTokenAuthenticator](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Security/Guard/JWTTokenAuthenticator.php) 
And you can also extend it:

```
namespace App\Security\Guard;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator as BaseAuthenticator;

class JWTTokenAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator

{
    // Your own logic
}
```

In services.yml

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    app.jwt_token_authenticator:
        class: App\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator
        parent: lexik_jwt_authentication.security.guard.jwt_token_authenticator            
        #---below 3 lines are absent in documentation
        public: true
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: false
```

Finally in security.yml:

```
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        # ...
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard: 
                authenticators:
                    - app.jwt_token_authenticator
```

for further information check in here: [Extending JWTTokenAuthenticator](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/6-extending-jwt-authenticator.md)